# SQL Query to add different tables data

Tags: mysql

I've two tables under which several columns are their, say for example
task_master and logtime.

**Taskmaster table have following columns :**

```
taskid
Actualhours
AssignedTo
createdDate
EmployeeHours
PlannedHours
status, 
task_name
task_key
```

**Logtime table as below :**

```
logid
date
empolyeid
hours
remarks
taskid
```

so my question is if some employee has worked on several task
e.g: ABC has worked on `taskid 1,2,3` and for `taskid 2` he has spent 5 hours and EFG has worked on `taskid 2,3,4` and for taskid 2 he has spent 14 hours,
my problem is i've to calculate the actual hours the both or more than that has spent over the same task.
so my Actualhours should be 19 hours..
Thanks well in advance.

I tried this command but it gives me the output of the employeeid, who has worked on some taskid, but i want to know how much time has been spent over some task by all the employees

```
SELECT
    logtime.employeeId
  , logtime.taskId
  , sum(hours) as EmployeeHours
  , task_master.Task_Key
  , task_master.ActualHours
  , task_master.Task_Name
  , task_master.AssignedToInJira
  , task_master.CreatedDate
  , task_master.UpdatedDate
  , task_master.Status
  , task_master.PlannedHours
  , task_master.Task_Description 
FROM logtime join task_master 
where logtime.taskId=task_master.taskId 
and logtime.employeeId=4 
GROUP By taskId,employeeId 
limit 0,1000
```

Comment: What have you done so far? give some insights about your db schema

Comment: Hi Surabhi,
I've db named test under which four tables are their employee_master(employeeid,email,name,password,role)
employee_task(id,employeeid,taskid)
logtime(logid,date,employeeid,hours,remarks,taskid)
is their along with
task_master(taskid,Actualhours ,AssignedTo,createdDate,EmployeeHours,PlannedHours,status,task_name,task_key)

Comment: do what do check the employee take more than actual hours or not? right ?

Comment: try to join the tables

Comment: SELECT logtime.employeeId,logtime.taskId,sum(hours) as EmployeeHours,task_master.Task_Key,task_master.ActualHours,task_master.Task_Name,task_master.AssignedToInJira,task_master.CreatedDate,task_master.UpdatedDate,task_master.Status,task_master.PlannedHours,task_master.Task_Description FROM logtime join task_master where logtime.taskId=task_master.taskId and logtime.employeeId=4 GROUP By taskId,employeeId limit 0,1000
i tried this command but it gives me the output of the employeeid, who has worked on some taskid, but i want to know how much time has been spent over some task by all the employe

Comment: My question is if say employeeid 4 has spent 4 hours for taskid 5
and employeeid 9 has spent  14 hours for taskid 5, so my actual hours for some taskid should be 18 hours.

Comment: in future please do not include your query as a comment, put it into your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the sum of all hours worked by the employees on a given task, right?

If yes then you can do:

```
 CREATE VIEW ACTUAL_HOURS AS
select taskid, sum(hours) as actual_hours
 from logtime
 group by taskid
 order by taskid;
```

THEN you join this view with task_master by taskid.

Comment: Yes, i mean the same. but output is not coming what i'm expecting

Comment: Could you post the schema and a little bit of sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: SELECT logtime.employeeId,logtime.taskId,sum(hours) as EmployeeHours,task_master.Task_Key,task_master.ActualHours,task_master.Task_Name,task_master.AssignedToInJira,task_master.CreatedDate,task_master.UpdatedDate,task_master.Status,task_master.PlannedHours,task_master.Task_Description FROM logtime cross join task_master where logtime.taskId=task_master.taskId and logtime.employeeId=4 GROUP By taskId,employeeId limit 0,1000


i want the output of ActualHours say for example 34 hours as employeeid 4 in itself has worked for 10 hours and other employee has workd 24 hours on the same task,.

Comment: yeah sure..i'm posting

Comment: Oh, understood. IMO, you will need to created a view with the select I scribbed above and then make the join with task_master by taskid instead of making the join directly with logtime. Got it?

Comment: do NOT include your query as a comment .... please. make the question more complete and easier to read instead

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
SELECT logtime.employeeId,logtime.taskId,sum(hours) as EmployeeHours,
task_master.Task_Key,task_master.ActualHours,task_master.Task_Name‌
​,task_master.AssignedToInJira,task_master.CreatedDate,
task_master.UpdatedDate,tas‌k_master.Status,task_master.PlannedHours,
ta.totalhours,
task_master.Task_Description FROM logtime join task_master on  
logtime.taskId=task_master.taskId join 
(select sum(hours) as totalhours ,taskId from logtime group by taskId) 
as ta on ta.taskId=task_master.taskId where
logtime.employeeId=4 GROUP By taskId,
employeeId limit 0,1000
```

Comment: i tried this one as well but it's not working Sathish.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want employeeid in the result, then do not include it in the query. in particular do not include it in the GROUP BY clause because hen you will get a new row for each employeeid on each taskid

```
SELECT
      logtime.taskId
    , SUM(logtime.hours) AS EmployeeHours
FROM logtime
      JOIN task_master ON logtime.taskId = task_master.taskId
WHERE logtime.employeeId = 4
GROUP BY
      logtime.taskId
;
```

For example if the query looked like this following **you will get more rows**

```
SELECT
      logtime.employeeId
    , logtime.taskId
    , SUM(logtime.hours) AS EmployeeHours
FROM logtime
      JOIN task_master ON logtime.taskId = task_master.taskId
WHERE logtime.employeeId = 4
GROUP BY
      logtime.employeeId
    , logtime.taskId
;
```

Now: because you use MySQL there is something you need to also understand. MySQL allows a "short cut" in the syntax of GROUP BY, but you should never use that short cut. For details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html this "extension" to GROUP BY in MySQL is not recommended.

So: for every column that does NOT use an aggregation function, you need to include that column in the GROUP BY clause.

Hence if you want more columns like the task name, then the query would look like this:

```
SELECT
      logtime.taskId
    , task_master.Task_Key
    , task_master.Task_Name
    , task_master.AssignedToInJira
    , task_master.CreatedDate
    , task_master.UpdatedDate
    , task_master.Status
    , task_master.PlannedHours
    , task_master.Task_Description
    , SUM(logtime.hours) AS EmployeeHours
FROM logtime
      JOIN task_master ON logtime.taskId = task_master.taskId
WHERE logtime.employeeId = 4
GROUP BY
      logtime.taskId
    , task_master.Task_Key
    , task_master.Task_Name
    , task_master.AssignedToInJira
    , task_master.CreatedDate
    , task_master.UpdatedDate
    , task_master.Status
    , task_master.PlannedHours
    , task_master.Task_Description
;
```

BUT, be a little careful because each column included in the GROUP BY might increase the number of rows.

Comment: i want the output like this
taskId employeeId EmployeeHours ActualHours
1              4                       22                      48
here actualhours mean the time spent over taskId 1 by all the employee

Comment: PLEASE, edit your question to include better details don't try adding details to every answer as comments it is just confusing for all involved. I strongly suggest you provide A) "sample data" and B) "the expected result" laid out neatly so we understand you